# How to show a number input bind to a double property as percentage or dollars in blazor?

Tags: input, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I need to have an input that show the double value 1.1799 as 117.99% and 0.667 as 66.70%.

How can i do this with a model property?

```
<input type="number" value="Ratio">


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public double? Ratio{ get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a custom input control with Bootstrap formatting that looks like this:

[image]

```cs
@using System.Linq.Expressions;

<div class="input-group mb-3">

    <InputNumber class="form-control" @AdditionalAttributes="@this.AdditionalAttributes"
                 Value="_value"
                 ValueChanged="(double? value) => this.OnValueChanged(value)"
                 ValueExpression="this.ValueExpression" />

    <span class="input-group-text">%</span>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public double? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<double?> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<double?>>? ValueExpression { get; set; }

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>? AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

    private double? _value => this.Value * 100;

    private async Task OnValueChanged(double? value)
        => await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value / 100);
}
```

And a demo:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Percent Control Demo</h1>

<InputPercent @bind-Value="_value" />

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2" >
    <pre>Value : @_value</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private double? _value;
}
```